# How do you create a new embedded document in an existing parent document in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm trying to delete the embedded document from a parent document, and then add another embedded document but I am getting an error.  Is my syntax not correct?

Error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for []:Array
```

Code

```
u = User.last
u.classes.destroy_all
u.classes.create(:name => "Philsophy") # I get the error right at this line
```

Ruby on Rails 3.0.3
Mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give your model structure.

Comment: `Mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20` seriously ? The latest version for this branch is 2.0.2. Try upgrading first.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship method **classes** returns an Array, not your base class.
To create and embed an object, you need to call the **new** method on the class,
then append it to **classes**.

Here is a working example that is probably close to what you intended.  Hope that it helps you move on.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embeds_many :classes, class_name: 'MyClass'
end

class MyClass
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  embedded_in :user
end
```

test/unit/user_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    User.delete_all
  end

  test "embedded doc" do
    User.create(name: 'Gary')
    assert_equal(1, User.count)
    u = User.last
    u.classes.destroy_all
    puts "u.classes.class: #{u.classes.class}"
    u.classes << MyClass.new(:name => 'Philosophy')
    user = User.find(u.id)
    assert_equal('Philosophy', user.classes.first.name)
    puts user.to_json
  end
end
```

test output

```
Run options: --name=test_embedded_doc

# Running tests:

u.classes.class: Array
{"_id":"4fc62aeb7f11baa5b0000001","classes":[{"_id":"4fc62aeb7f11baa5b0000002","name":"Philosophy"}],"name":"Gary"}
.

Finished tests in 0.009929s, 100.7151 tests/s, 201.4302 assertions/s.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary but that didn't work.  I found out how to make it not error out.  Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823599/why-is-mongoid-not-allowing-for-the-creation-of-a-new-embedded-document-when-usi

Comment: You didn't supply your model for "class", did is the name "Class", as seems to be indicated by the answer for the question you reference?  If so, this is a collision with Ruby's Class, which is of fundamental importance to Ruby, and you really don't want to reappropriate it.

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/v3/relations.html#embeds_many

is helpful and points to many ways where you can add new objects to an existing object such as:

```
band.albums.build(name: "Violator")
band.albums.new(name: "Violator")
```

and if you have multiple objects

```
band.albums.concat(
  Album.new(name: "Violator"),
  Album.new(name: "101")
)
```